# C# Regex.Split is working differently than JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, cjk

I'm trying to convert [this long JS regex](https://github.com/trkbt10/mikan.js/blob/d69f3270d4eb9c6e1363865602cd9fd27bab061b/src/mikan.js#L16) to C#.

The **JS code** below gives 29 items in an array starting from `["","常","","に","","最新","、","最高"...]`

```
var keywords = /(\&nbsp;|[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,}|[一-龠々〆ヵヶゝ]+|[ぁ-んゝ]+|[ァ-ヴー]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+|[ａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ０-９]+)/g;
var source = '常に最新、最高のモバイル。Androidを開発した同じチームから。';
var result = source.split(keywords);
```

But the **C# code** below gives *a non-splitted single item* in `string[]`.

```
var keywords = @"/(\&nbsp;|[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,}|[一-龠々〆ヵヶゝ]+|[ぁ-んゝ]+|[ァ-ヴー]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+|[ａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ０-９]+)/g";
var source = @"常に最新、最高のモバイル。Androidを開発した同じチームから。";
var result = Regex.Split(source, keywords);
```

Many questions in Stack Overflow are covering relatively simple expressions only, so I cannot find my mistakes.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your RegEx is wrong, you should not start and end with `'/'` or `'/g'` You specify a string in the constructor, not a JavaScript Regex (with '/    /' syntax.). That's a Javascript syntax.

Actually the same applies to JavaScript when you use a string constructor like this:

`var regex = new RegExp('//');` // This will match 2 slashes

Comment: Thanks, I removed first `/` and last `/g` then it works.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a C# example code

```
string keywords = @"(\&nbsp;|[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,}|[一-龠々〆ヵヶゝ]+|[ぁ-んゝ]+|[ァ-ヴー]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+|[ａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ０-９]+)";
string source = @"常に最新、最高のモバイル。Androidを開発した同じチームから。";
string [] res = Regex.Split(source, keywords);

string single = "";
foreach ( string str in res )
    single += "'" + str + "',";
Console.WriteLine("{0}", single);
```